# How actually values get assigned to object reference(actual memory,allocated by new) which are initialized by Constructor?

Tags: java

```
class box
{
  double height,width,depth;

  box(double h,double w,double d)
  {
   height=h;
   width=w;
   depth=d;
  }
}

class boxdemo7
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  double vol1,vol2;
  box mybox1=new box(10,12,16);

 } 
}
```

In these program in the `box` class I declared three double type variables, and I initialize those with constructor meaning I set the state of the object which is using the constructor. My Question is `height,width,depth` got memory allocated for them when declared within `box` class, so by using constructor they got values `10,12,16` and these values taken by object `mybox1`. So `mybox1`'s memory location has these values ?or these variables memory has these values and a reference to those are stored to objets referred location ? How memory works while an objects internal state gets the values ?

Answer (score 3):

Primitive types are passed by value, unlike objects. So in this particular case the values 10, 12 and 16 will be assigned to the fields inside your box object. With objects, on the other hand, it will depend on your implementation of the constructor. If you use a simple assignment operator the field will get a reference to the passed object, and changes to the passed object will change the object the field refers to. If you create a new object based on the passed object they will remain independent.

Try this code:

```
public class Test {

    static class sample{
        int primitive;
        int[] object;

        sample(int prim, int[] obj){
            primitive = prim;
            object = obj;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        int primram = 0;

        int[] objectParameter = new int[1];

        sample demonstration = new sample(primram, 
                objectParameter);

        System.out.printf("Old Values: %d, %d%n", 
            demonstration.primitive, 
            demonstration.object[0]);

        primram++;

        objectParameter[0] = primram;

        System.out.printf("New Values: %d, %d%n", 
            demonstration.primitive, 
            demonstration.object[0]);

        objectParameter = new int[1];

        System.out.printf("Unchanged Values: %d, %d%n", 
            demonstration.primitive, 
            demonstration.object[0]);
    }
}
```

You should get output:

```
Old Values: 0, 0
New Values: 0, 1
Unchanged Values: 0, 1
```

Notice that the first value, the primitive, did not change when we incremented our `primitiveParameter` value, because it had already been passed by value and no longer had any relationship with the primitive field inside the object.

Setting `objectParameter[0]` did change the value inside our sample object because arrays are objects. When you say `object = obj` in a constructor you point `object` to the data that `obj` points to. Since they both point to the same place, they both see changes.